# How to create and update text file using ajax and php?

Tags: php, ajax

When I call my PHP file directly, it makes a text file exactly as I expected. But when I use AJAX, it doesn't make the text file.

I gave pemissions to directory and files: `chmod(0777)` and setup `allow_url_fopen` as "ON".
I made sure the AJAX is calling `indexing.php`, but no text files are created.

What's going wrong?

```
$('#btn_index').on('click', function(){
  $.ajax({url: "/indexing.php", success: function(result){
    alert("Indexing is finished");
  }});
});
```

indexing.php

```
<?php

$fWrite = fopen(__DIR__."/indexOfFiles.txt","w+") or die('Cannot open file:  ');

if ($handle = opendir('./data/pdffiles')) {

    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {

        if ($entry != "." && $entry != "..") {


            $wrote = fwrite($fWrite, "$entry".PHP_EOL);
        }
    }
}


closedir($handle);
fclose($fWrite);

$fWrite = fopen(__DIR__."/arrays.txt","w+") or die('Cannot open file:  ');
$wrote = fwrite($fWrite, '{"data": []}');

fclose($fWrite);
?>
```

Comment: What's the value of `result` in your `success` handler? It looks like you're missing a closing brace `}` in your PHP script.

Comment: It is part of indexing.php file, result is html content for the page, I have no idea why it contains those contents.

Comment: The HTML content for which page? Does `indexing.php` have HTML content?

Comment: no, After I removed all output( I mean echo and var_dump statements) from indexing.php, result still contains html content which is another page.

Comment: Troubleshooting 101: Have you opened your network panel in your browser's developer console, and seen what the network call looks like? Does it run? What does the response look like?  Based on your comments, it looks like you're hitting a 404 error which has a redirect....

Comment: I've checked that, request type is GET and status is 200, but response is html content(It is exactly index page of the site.)

Comment: Are you sure `indexing.php` is in the root folder of the site? Maybe you've got some handling that redirects 404s to the index page...

Comment: For this to work, you need to read ALL of the comments.  You've now got TWO people recommending you have a 404 redirect, and that your path is not correct.

Comment: no, the page I worked on is placed on the part of the server. So I called index.php (this is not index page of the site, it is only for my work for the specific functionality) like this http://www.custom.com/cabinet/index.php, but the result contains of html content of http://www.custom.com/index.php page.

Comment: Is the PHP file that writes the files called `index.php` or `indexing.php`? If it's in the "cabinet" folder, your AJAX call should reflect that (e.g. `url: "/cabinet/index.php"`).

Comment: indexing.php which makes index file for finding pdf files shortly, it can cause a bit confusion, sorry.

Comment: right, I'm an idiot, ll give a shot.

Comment: many thanks, you all friends, it works well. Thank you showdev and cale_b